# route53 naked domain not reaching amazon elastic load balancer

Tags: django, apache, dns, amazon-route53

I`m currently using route53 for 2 domains that points to the same website.

Lets assume they are **www.example.com** and **www.example.com.xx**, I`ve created 2 hosted zones and maintained the configuration created by default. So, initially I had entries for **NS** an **SOA** in each hosted zone.

My EC2 instances are behind Elastic Load Balancer, so my first step was to create aliases for both domains and it naked domains, having the following scenario:

> **www.example.com**
>
> name                             type                   value
>   example.com.               NS                    Generated value
>   example.com.               SOA                 Generated value
>   example.com.                 A                      ALIAS to my ELB
>   *.example.com.               A                      ALIAS to my ELB
>   www.example.com.        A                      ALIAS to my ELB
>
> **www.example.com.xx**
>
> name                                  type                   value
>   example.com.xx.               NS                    Generated value
>   example.com.xx.               SOA                 Generated value
>   example.com.xx.                 A                      ALIAS to my ELB
>   *.example.com.xx.               A                      ALIAS to my ELB
>   www.example.com.xx.        A                      ALIAS to my ELB

Both domains are pointing to the same ELB, where Apache configs to **example.com**. Then, my Django app subdomain middleware redirects to example.com(301) if request.get_host contains the **.com.xx** substring.

It is working perfect for both www.example.com and example.com as for www.example.com.xx, **my problem is** with example.com.br that never reaches my server.

I`ve already tried to make a PTR entry example.com.br -> www.example.com.br, but it was not the solution.

Anyone can point where my DNS config for this naked domain is failing?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly lets worry about example.com.br. [www.example.com.br we will take later]

Did you made changes on ur Domain registrar; so as to give DNS servers as that of Amazon ? What is the output you are getting when u do :
nslookup example.com.br

also what is the output for 
ping example.com.br

Comment: Hello Deepak, thanks for your reply. 

I did change domain servers delegation to Amazon NS servers through 3rd party domain provider that deals with the registrar. 

Now looking for it, I realized that I`m able to manage DNS table in both systems (route53 and brazilian domain provider), I don`t believe it is an expected behaviour. I will now skip this 3rd party provider that is not needed anymore and update the thread soon.

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday night I was able to redirect my naked domain properly, it was a bug in my brazilian provider that was dealing with the registrar. Actually, I just gave them back the control of the DNS table and took it away (returning it to route53).

Anyway, they were being used as a bridge to the registrar since I was migrating. Now I`m dealing directly with registro.br and the problem is gone.